# Unable to write requirements.txt on Visual Studio Code using pip freeze

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, requirements.txt

I am trying to deploy my python app.py with a docker container.
I am trying to write my dependencies into a requirements.txt file using:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

however, I am getting this error:

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\ids564flask\virtual\Scripts\python.exe"  "C:\ids594flask\virtual\Scripts\pip.exe" freeze': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I am working in an activated virtual environment (the folder is named virtual, as you can see above).

Comment: Are you running this in the terminal window? Do you get the same error in just Command Prompt?

Comment: May i know if you ever reached my answer? Has your question been resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Use `python -m pip` instead:

[image]

I can reproduce your error, and after resetting vscode with [this guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/setup/setup-overview#_how-can-i-do-a-clean-uninstall-of-vs-code), reopening the virtual environment then executing `pip` command still throws this error, unless I create a new virtual environment.

And if `python -m pip` doesn't work in your machine, pleasse try [VS Code Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/), It doesn't have such error.